# force line breaks in long character strings that contain highlighted text (seqsplit does not work here)

Tags: line-breaking, colorbox, seqsplit

I have a long string of characters containing highlighted text by way of a colorbox. Inside it, `\seqsplit` is ignored. How can I force line breaks within the highlighted text?

Please note: `\seqsplit` does not allow any other commands inside its environment. Thus, I get an error when putting `\seqsplit` outside of the `\colorbox`.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage{seqsplit}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\newcommand{\reducedstrut}{\vrule width 0pt height .9\ht\strutbox depth .9\dp\strutbox\relax}
\newcommand{\yellow}[1]{%
    \begingroup
    \setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}%  
    \colorbox{yellow}{\reducedstrut#1\/}%
    \endgroup
}

\begin{document}

\seqsplit{TAAGAACTACTCTTTGGAGCATGTCATCATAGATCCATATTTCAATCGAATTACTTCTCAGATGCGTAGTTGTGGAGAAGATGTCACAGAAATCGAAGTGAAACCTGATGGTTCTTGGCGCGCGAAGACAGAATC}
\yellow{\seqsplit{ACACTGCACGGTATGCTCCTCTTCTTGTTCATGGTCATGATCCTTATATGAGCAGGGAAAGTCCAGTTTAGACTTGTAGTTAGTTACTCTTCGTTATAGGATTTGGATTTCTTGCGTGTTTATGGTTTTAGTTTCCCTCCTTTGATGAATAAAATTGAATCTTGTATGAGTTTCATATCCATGTTGTGAATCTTTTTGCAGACGCAGCTAG}}
\seqsplit{GATTCTGTCTTCGCGCGCCAAGAACCATCAGGTTTCACTTCGATTTCTGTGACATCTTCTCCACAACTACGCATCTGAGAAGTAATTCGATTGAAATATGGATCTATGATGACATGCTCCAAAGAGTAGTTCTTAAGACAGATAGGGCATTGCCACTTCCTCGACCTTTGATTCATTTCAACAAAGACGTCAAGATCAAAGCAGCCCATGTGTATACAAGGTTTGAATCTTCCAGCAACTTTCATCCCCC}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can coerce `soul` to cooperate, but without `seqsplit`.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\seqsplit}{om}
 {
  \group_begin:
  \setlength{\spaceskip}{0pt plus 0.2pt}
  \__carl_seqsplit_load:n { #2 }
  \IfNoValueTF { #1 }
   {
    \__carl_seqsplit_simple:
   }
   {
    \__carl_seqsplit_color:n { #1 }
   }
  \hspace{\spaceskip}
  \group_end:
 }

\seq_new:N \l__carl_seqsplit_seq

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__carl_seqsplit_load:n
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__carl_seqsplit_seq { } { #1 }
 }
\cs_new:Nn \__carl_seqsplit_simple:
 {
  \seq_use:Nn \l__carl_seqsplit_seq { ~ }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__carl_seqsplit_color:n
 {
  \sethlcolor{#1}
  \AddToHook{cmd/SOUL@hlpreamble/after}{\setlength{\spaceskip}{0pt plus 0.2pt}}
  \exp_args:Ne \hl { \__carl_seqsplit_simple: }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\seqsplit{TAAGAACTACTCTTTGGAGCATGTCATCATAGATCCATATTTCAATCGAATTACTTCTCAGATG%
  CGTAGTTGTGGAGAAGATGTCACAGAAATCGAAGTGAAACCTGATGGTTCTTGGCGCGCGAAGACAGAATC}%
\seqsplit[yellow]{ACACTGCACGGTATGCTCCTCTTCTTGTTCATGGTCATGATCCTTATATGAGCAGG%
  GAAAGTCCAGTTTAGACTTGTAGTTAGTTACTCTTCGTTATAGGATTTGGATTTCTTGCGTGTTTATGGTTT%
  TAGTTTCCCTCCTTTGATGAATAAAATTGAATCTTGTATGAGTTTCATATCCATGTTGTGAATCTTTTTGCAGACGCAGCTAG}%
\seqsplit{GATTCTGTCTTCGCGCGCCAAGAACCATCAGGTTTCACTTCGATTTCTGTGACATCTTCTCCAC%
  AACTACGCATCTGAGAAGTAATTCGATTGAAATATGGATCTATGATGACATGCTCCAAAGAGTAGTTCTTAA%
  GACAGATAGGGCATTGCCACTTCCTCGACCTTTGATTCATTTCAACAAAGACGTCAAGATCAAAGCAGCCCA%
  TGTGTATACAAGGTTTGAATCTTCCAGCAACTTTCATCCCCC}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is amazing! In case anyone wants to know: It also works within tables (I tried it in tabularx).